# Proving ${l\choose n}+nl-{d+n\choose d}<0$ for $n\geq 6$, $d\geq 3$, $l<d+n-1$

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

Let $n\geq 6$ and $d\geq 3$. Prove that if $l<d+n-1$, then
$${l\choose n}+nl-{d+n\choose d}<0.$$
This is the necessary condition in my paper. Experiments show that it is true and $<0$. I tried by expanding but could not find any special for showing that it is $<0$. Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because$$
\binom{l}{n} < \binom{d + n - 1}{n}, \quad nl < n(d + n - 1),
$$
then it suffices to prove that$$
\binom{d + n}{d} \geqslant \binom{d + n - 1}{n} + n(d + n - 1).
$$

Since\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{} \binom{d + n}{d} - \binom{d + n - 1}{n} = \binom{d + n}{d} - \binom{d + n - 1}{d - 1}\\
&= \binom{d + n - 1}{d} = \frac{1}{d!} (d + n - 1) \cdots (n + 1)n\\
&= \frac{1}{d(d - 1)}·\binom{d + n - 2}{d - 2}·n(d + n - 1),
\end{align*}
then it suffices to prove that$$
\binom{d + n - 2}{d - 2} \geqslant d(d - 1),
$$
which is true in that\begin{align*}
\binom{d + n - 2}{d - 2} &\geqslant \binom{d + 5 - 2}{d - 2} = \binom{d + 5 - 2}{5}\\
&= \frac{1}{5!} (d + 3)(d + 2)(d + 1)·d(d - 1)\\
&\geqslant \frac{1}{5!} (3 + 3)(3 + 2)(3 + 1)·d(d - 1) = d(d - 1).
\end{align*}

Comment: It turns out that $n\geqslant5$ suffices.